# Scope to consider when determining navigability?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

When deciding whether ClassA can "navigate to" ClassB, do you only consider the fields/attributes of ClassA or do you also consider whether any methods of ClassA actually "navigate to" any objects of ClassB? Or do you consider whether some methods of ClassA merely temporarily hold a reference to any objects of ClassB?

In other words: Let's say I have a ClassA, which does not have any fields of type ClassB. However, I have a method ClassA.method1(ClassB b). When the method is called, it extracts information from b by calling b.method2(), does something accordingly, and then goes out of scope, but a reference to b is not stored permanently within ClassA. Do I indicate that ClassA can navigate to ClassB?

More simply, let's say that ClassA.method1(ClassB b) merely passes b on to some other object and never calls any methods on b. Do I indicate that ClassA **can** navigate to ClassB merely because it momentarily holds a reference to ClassB?

Or, do I indicate that ClassA can Navigate to ClassB if-and-only-if ClassA has a field of type ClassB?

Answer (score 1):

Navigability used to mean that a particular class owned a property through which that class could access that property’s type. Full stop. It has nothing to do with operations or implementation methods.

Now navigability means very little and an explicit “ball” notation tells you that a class, and not an association, owns a property. The reason for the change was that there was nothing to prevent a class from navigating when an association owned a property. (E.g., consider querying an RDBMS across a relationship table representing an association.) I don’t like the ball notation at all, but it is what it is.

Comment: Nobody likes that ball. It's just a "Uh, what's that?" to anybody (except a few nerds). Unfortunately it's th standard now.

Answer (score 0):

Navigability is something you don't really need. It just means "there will be some attribute accessing the other class but in the current design phase I don't know how to call it". Those implicit attributes are however mostly obvious. From my experience there are only rare cases where you actually should use navigation to clear up certain aspects. In most cases I just use a plain undirected Association. In a later design phase I add a role name and use the dot notation to make it an owned property.

For the case where an operation uses another class either as parameter or result and where you don't have an explicit attribute you just use a Dependency relation.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to my question. I did not ask for opinions as to whether people choose to use navigability indicators.

Comment: Thomas answer sounds good for me. In short, navigability meaningwill depend of your kind of project and model usage (documentation, code generation, BD generation, etc.). One thing which is certain is that navigeability is related to UML association so it is not relevant between an Operation and a Class.If a method uses an another class as parameter, you already have a "relation" between them at the metamodel level. If a method uses another class in its code and you want to express it I would use a Dependency between the operation or it class owner and the second class.

Comment: @RedBeard: It sounds as if you are saying that my examples are actually moot because inserting an association connector in this instance would be redundant. Rather than clutter up the diagram with additional association connectors, one merely relies on the association implied by the parameter listed for the operation. Therefore, it would only be necessary to insert said association line if a class was affected which wasn't obvious by the parameters listed. Thank you. That clears it up for me. Let me know if I am correct and I will write up a complete answer.